# My LSTM is struck with local minima

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, lstm

My LSTM Accuracy is low and is the same even if I go for higher epochs.

I tried varying the optimizer/changing the batch size, but it still remains the same.

My data: sequence length is 300, so its 300*6 dimensions

Attached the results below:

[image]

Comment: You can try:
changing the sequence length, LSTM units, adding more LSTM/Dense layers, update the dropout.

Comment: CNN is giving good accuracy .For LSTM ,  Drop out - I tried varying between 0.2 -0.5 , But no luck .
Will try changing sequence length . Can I decrease the length and see the results ? Or is my my model not learning ?

Comment: How much data do you use for training?

Comment: 14000 records ,1800 features